# Can new clutch slave cylinder make car less revvy?

Tags: clutch-cylinder

Civic coupe vti 1999.

After I changed my clutch slave cylinder it seemed the revs seem to go up slower and I need to apply more gas now to prevent It from stalling and I shift gears later now.

I believe that if you have an old clutch it might be more revvy(slip) and if you never had a new clutch getting a new one would mak the car seem less revvy as it’s not slipping?  Can a older clutch slave cylinder cause this symptom too and so what I am experiencing now is just how the car was designed?  It feels more quiter and similar to a normal Car In low rpm than before the clutch Slave replacement were it was more revvy which I thought was how the car is meant to be and seemed nicer.

New clutch was pagid brand and original was most likely Honda.

Thing is I found the slave leaking recently prior to which I don’t believe it was leaking.  So if the Slavs was worn, in what way could it be worn to cause higher revs or must it be leaking for this to happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A leaking clutch slave cylinder may cause the clutch not to fully disengage, but you will most likely have noticed this when changing gear.

The clutch slave cylinder has no direct effect on how quick the revs go up/down. This is mostly affected by the weight of the flywheel. The heavier the flywheel, the slower the revs to up. Also if the clutch is not fully disengaged, it takes longer for the revs to go up (and the car may also start rolling if it's in gear obviously).

Comment: OTOH, if the clutch slave cylinder is defective and the clutch is not thereby fully disengaging, the clutch will slip. That will allow an unexpected increase in engine speed when the throttle is opened. The driver should then perceive that the vehicle's acceleration is impaired.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica If the clutch is not fully disengaged, the engine will rev slower than when it is fully disengaged, simply because of drag caused by the slipping.

Comment: I disagree. If the clutch is partially engaged (another way to say "not fully disengaged") then some engine power will be transmitted to the gearbox, and some of the engine power will be lost to clutch slippage, causing more clutch wear and generating heat. The altered relationship between engine revs and car speed will be felt, and also seen as the rev counter rises more quickly than the car's speed over the ground warrants.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding going on. What you mean is when you're driving normally, when you press the gas, the revs will go up quicker with a partially engaged clutch than they will if the clutch if fully engaged. I agree.

What I mean is when you press the clutch, revs go up quicker when the cluch is fully disengaged than if the clutch is partially engaged.

Comment: We seem to be describing the same thing from different perspectives.